# load_and_authorize_resource with multiwork model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I've got a Model with a multi-word name: `AmountType`

So I'm trying to get that to load an authorize correctly using cancan with the following code.

```
class AmountTypesController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

I expect that the instance variable will be called: `@amount_types` in the index action.

But when I load the view I get the following error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

12: 
13: <% @amount_types.each do |amount_type| %>
14:
```

How do I force cancan to load the model with the correct name? or is something else wrong that I'm not seeing?